# Select min and max date with time providing only date part (yyyy/MM/dd)

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
2012-11-23 05:49:26.000  
2012-11-23 07:55:43.000  
2012-11-23 13:59:56.000  
2012-11-26 07:51:13.000  
2012-11-26 10:23:31.000  
2012-11-26 10:25:09.000  
2012-11-26 16:22:22.000  
2012-11-27 07:30:03.000  
2012-11-27 08:53:47.000  
2012-11-27 10:40:55.000
```

From this when I pass `2012-11-27` .... I want output min `2012-11-27 07:30:03.000`, max `2012-11-27 10:40:55.000`

Comment: Please post your current code and what your specific problem with it is

Answer (score 2):

All you need to understand is the date comparisons:

```
select min(col), max(col)
from table t
where col >= '2012-11-27' and
      col < dateadd(day, 1, '2012-11-27');
```

The date comparisons are very consciously done using two comparisons rather than:

```
where cast(col as date) = '2012-11-27'
```

The first method is a good habit because it is more likely to result in SQL Server using an index on the column, particularly for more complicated expressions.

Comment: Thanks..Its working for me..but what is logic behind  the dateadd(day, 1, '2012-11-27');

Comment: @ShivajiKokate . . . That gets the earliest time on the next day.  So, the logic is the same as for the second comparison, but the expression is sargable.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select   Max(DateAttribute)
        ,Min(DateAttribute)
From    Table As t
Where   Dateadd(D, 0, Datediff(D, 0, DateAttribute)) = @DateFilter  ----your parameter
```

above will work in SQL Server 2005 as well without any change.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the between keyword for date comparisons. I also included a sample table declaration that matches your data.

```
DECLARE @tempDates AS TABLE (myDate DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @tempDates VALUES
('2012-11-23 05:49:26.000'),
('2012-11-23 07:55:43.000'),  
('2012-11-23 13:59:56.000'),  
('2012-11-26 07:51:13.000'),  
('2012-11-26 10:23:31.000'),  
('2012-11-26 10:25:09.000'),  
('2012-11-26 16:22:22.000'),  
('2012-11-27 07:30:03.000'),  
('2012-11-27 08:53:47.000'),  
('2012-11-27 10:40:55.000')

SELECT 
    MIN(myDate) AS 'Min', MAX(myDate) AS 'Max' 
FROM 
    @tempDates 
WHERE 
    myDate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-11-27') 
    AND DATEADD(D,1, CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-11-27'))
```